# Having Trouble With Centering Multiple "div" Elements

Tags: html, css

I have a web page with 5 div elements and I'm trying to center these divs in the middle of the screed. (flexible mode). This image describes my goal. please help me if you can.

http://www.mediafire.com/view/8v8acb404ikbfja/3.jpg

And this is my CSS codes that belongs to the left image:

```
#container{
    clear: both;
    border: 3px dashed red;
}

#container .divs{
    width: 360px;
    height: 230px;
    margin: 60px;
    float: left;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 30px;
    border: 3px dashed red;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the floats and make the divs `display:inline-block` then add `text-align:center` to the #container

[JSfiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GQm77/1/embedded/result/)

Comment: i loooooooooooooooooooooooooove you

Answer (score 0):

use `display: inline-block;` instead `float:left;`